# How can I create a new Firefox profile

Tags: xubuntu, firefox

I use Xubuntu 64 bit version, and i trying make a new profile of Firefox on this system. In windows was command `firefox -p` but on Ubuntu doesn't work.

Comment: what error does it gave you?

Answer (score 3):

That should be:

```
firefox --ProfileManager
```

It also works with an *uppercase* `-P`:

```
firefox -P
```

Comment: @Samantha.G As you're a new user here, please take the 2-minutes [tour] to learn some basic things about our site. You will e.g. learn, that unlike on a forum, we're working with votes here instead of "Thank you"-comments. So please, as this answer seems to have solved your question, mark it as accepted by clicking the grey tick on the left of it. Thank you for participating and welcome on AskUbuntu.com!